# Is this a virus or an sdk attachment?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, sdk, virus

I am coding c++ and OpenGL in Visual Studio. When after i run my program, i see these output messages

```
'test_001.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\uxtheme.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test_001.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\combase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test_001.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\Ibrahim\AppData\Local\Temp\0Kraken0510DevProps.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test_001.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ole32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test_001.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\psapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
```

lots of PDB files couldnt be open, however one of them is this:

```
'test_001.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\Ibrahim\AppData\Local\Temp\0Kraken0510DevProps.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
```

i was just wondering what this is. i have a razor kraken head set, i send feedback message to them, waiting for answer but, i also want to ask here. is this a virus or an sdl thingy?

Comment: That's just normal. All those DLLs simply don't ship with debug information.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the debug information(PDB file) for the DLL associated with your headset. There is no virus there.

Comment: One thing to note is that you most likely don't need the debug information. It's useful if you want to understand how your application interacts with the OS or perhaps you think you have found a bug in the OS and you want to help debug it to send information to Microsoft.